# How to create a barcode with GS1128 format in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, fonts, barcode

I want to create a barcode with GS1128 format, I know that is a type of font but I don´t know how can I create the code to create one, I accept suggestions, thanks.

Comment: To make gs1-128 using vb.net or c#, you'll implement a barcode maker component which supports gs1-128 standards into your  projects. There are some components out there like http://www.avapose.com/csharp_barcode/

Comment: This is not the kind of question for Stackoverflow. SO is here for you when you've already [searched and researched](/help/how-to-ask) your subject, and you've started writing code, but the code you've written doesn't do what you expect it to do, and after *more* searching and researching, you still can't figure out why. There's a few [edge cases](/help/on-topic) that cover other kinds of questions, but "please tell me what to do" is not one of those. If you've done your research, at the very least update your post and explain what you found and why none of that works for you.